# Laravel 5 - Use Auth::check() in view

Tags: authentication, laravel, view

I want to show a logout-button inside of my view if the user is logged in.

I've tried this:

```
@if( Auth::check() )
    <li><a href="{{url('/')/auth/logout}}">Logout</a></li>
@endif
```

But I'm getting this error-message:

```
Use of undefined constant auth - assumed 'auth'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the `Auth::check()`, but rather in this code:

```
{{url('/')/auth/logout}}
```

which translates into this php code:

```
<?php echo url('/')/auth/logout ?>
```

As you can see, php thinks that `/auth/logout` is php code and tries to execute it as such - but of course, it can't.

What you want is probably something like this:

```
{{ url('/') }}/auth/logout
```

or

```
{{ url('/auth/logout') }}
```

... although of course, it depends on what you're trying to link to. :)

Comment: Or `{{ url('/') . '/auth/logout' }}` although I'd definitely prefer `{{ url('auth/logout') }}`